# What is the most appropriate word in the given sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

> The treasure was hidden ______ a big shore.
>
> (a) on (b) underneath
> (c) toward (d) off

Now, I'm confused between a) on and d) off.

If we use off, it would mean that treasure is near the shore but not **ON**  the shore. It just doesn't feel correct to me. Please give some insights.

Comment: All answers except (c) could be correct, depending on where exactly the treasure is hidden.

Comment: **a big shore** is a most unlikely description, given that the shore is the endless strip separating the sea from the land. **a big beach** would be far more likely.

Comment: I understand but what would be the most appropriate answer? I mean I HAVE TO answer the question anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out *a big shore* is a very awkward phrase.

> The treasure was hidden on the shore

is syntactically correct but semantically odd as you would normally bury treasure.

> The treasure was hidden underneath the shore

that would be correct

> The treasure was hidden toward the shore

No, *toward* implies movement.

> The treasure was hidden off the shore

So the pirates went some way *off the shore*, away from land into the sea to hide the treasure or more plausibly into the land area behind the shore.

Comment: In the last case, "off the shore" is not the equivalent of "offshore". It would mean exactly as the questioner postulates: 'somewhere away from the shore, but likely nearby'. It COULD mean "offshore", but it could also mean past the shoreline on land.

Comment: @MarkGB yes, thinking about it a bit more deeply sensible pirates would have gone inland.

Comment: That got a good laugh out of me!